# Is there anyway I can get backtrace in a function inside aosp?

Tags: android, android-source, backtrace

I'm new to Android and AOSP. I have a requirement where I need to get the backtrace in function that is inside one of AOSP file. I tried integrating the `#include<execinfo.h>` but then the it won't build. I have also read about different android specific methods like `unwind`, but then I need know how can I get it integrated in the code.

> fatal error: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.